# What algorithm to use to match beginning of strings

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, language-agnostic

I have a lot of strings that I would like to match against a search term.

Example:

```
folks
fort
garage
grabbed
grandmother
habit
happily
harry
heading
hunter
```

I'll like to search for the string "ha" and the algorithm to return the start of the list where where strings begin with "ha", in this case "habit".

Of course I don't one to go one by one since the list is huge. I can do some pre processing to sort the list or put it into a structure that makes this sort of search fasts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming there are to be multiple searches of prefixes, if you only need to search the list once it makes no sense to sort it.

Comment: How big is the list ? Is it terabytes of data or a few million entries ?

Answer (score 3):

Well you want a sorted structure of some type.  You could get away with a TreeMap or a Radix Tree (Radix will save you some space).  The overhead of this will be the sort operation or the overhead of inserting into a sorted data structure.  However, once sorted a binary search will give you `logN+1` worst case lookup performance.

Of note `Lucene` uses Radix Trees afaik

Comment: I looked into a binary search, but I'm not sure how to tune it so it'll return the first entry "habit", since if I use a compare function that just matches the beginning of the string I would stop just at hitting any of the matches, rather than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can always look at [Patricia Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree). They are almost perfectly suited for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

A [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is what you are looking for.

Comment: id lean towards the radix tree, saves more space

Answer (score 1):

Your post leaves too many questions unanswered. My interpretation is that you want to create a dictionary from an unordered list of words. But then when you search for `ha`, what is it that you really want?

Do you want

1. the first word that starts with `ha`?
2. the index of the first word that starts with `ha`?
3. to have easy access to all the words that start with `ha`?

If you want `1` and/or `3`, then the person who says [trie](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/trie/is_word) is correct. (The link I give you has an easy to read implementation).

If `2` is what you want, then can you talk about a use-case? If not, then you are looking at using a [string search algorithm](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/string_search_algorithm/kmp_string_search_algorithm). Without more details, it's difficult to give more precise advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has many fuzzy areas.  Depending on exactly what your requirements are you might find that the [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) string searching method is of use to you.